# How to refactor a grammar to be suitable for recursive descent?

Tags: formal-grammars, compilers, ambiguity

I'm trying to learn how to use a recursive descent parser, and reading on [this page](http://www.cs.engr.uky.edu/~lewis/essays/compilers/rec-des.html) I find this example:

$S \rightarrow AB \\
A \rightarrow a \\
A \rightarrow SA \\
B \rightarrow b \\
B \rightarrow SB$

By substituting $S$ we arrive at:

$S \rightarrow AB \\
A \rightarrow a \\
A \rightarrow ABA \\
B \rightarrow b \\
B \rightarrow ABB$

In an attempt to eliminate left recursion, we create $A'$:

$1.\text{ }S \rightarrow AB \\
2.\text{ }A \rightarrow aA' \\
3.\text{ }A' \rightarrow \epsilon \\
4.\text{ }A' \rightarrow BaA' \\
5.\text{ }B \rightarrow b \\
6.\text{ }B \rightarrow aA'BB$

At this point, it is stated

> The grammar is now in a form that will lend itself to recursive descent parser construction after some factoring and substitution.

I know that the problem production is $B \rightarrow aA'BB$ because it references $A'$, which comes before it. I can't figure out how to refactor it so that it does not refer to $A'$. When attempting to generate a series of rules that can be used to prove that a given string is in this grammar, I have trouble determining whether to use rule 3 or 4. Is this an $LL(k)$ grammar? If so, what is $k$?